# Question about chain complexes with coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, tensor-products

Given an abelian group $G$ and a topological space $X$, we can write the singular chain complex of $X$ with coefficients in $G$ as $$\Delta_*(X;G):= \Delta_*(X) \otimes_{\mathbb Z}G.$$ In Tammo tom Dieck's book *Algebraic Topology*, he says that chains in $\Delta_*(X; G)$ can be written as formal sums $$\sum_\sigma a_\sigma\sigma,$$ where $a_\sigma\in G$ for all singular simplices $\sigma$ in $X$. My question is, why is it that chains in $\Delta_*(X; G)$ can be written in this way, given that $\Delta_*(X; G) := \Delta_*(X)\otimes_{\mathbb Z} G$?

Comment: $\Delta_*(X)$ is a free $\mathbb Z$-module. Does that help?

Comment: @peterag Does that imply that $\Delta_*(X) \otimes G\simeq G$? Or something along those lines?

Comment: General fact:  $\Big(\oplus_{i\in I} M_i\Big) \otimes N \simeq \oplus_{i \in I} (M_i\otimes N)$. Here, $N= G$, and $M_i= \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Ah, so because $\Delta_p(X) \simeq \bigoplus_{i \in I} \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z \otimes G \simeq G$ $\forall G \in \mathsf {Ab}$, we have that $\Delta_*(X;G) \simeq \bigoplus _{i \in I} G$?

Comment: Right.  and a reference for the 'general fact' is Lang's Algebra, XVI Cor. 2.2 (I just went and  looked it up now! )

Comment: Thank you! I came across the fact that for any abelian group $G$, $\mathbb Z \otimes G \simeq G$ in Munkres' Elements of Algebraic Topology, theorem 50.2.

Comment: Sorry, the star in the last $\Delta$ of my 2nd comment should be a $p$.

Comment: Right, and - just to be clear - one also needs the fact that 'tensor product commutes with direct sums' (which was my 'general fact')

Comment: Yes, thank you again!

Comment: And - one last point - the '$\simeq$'s here are canonical: that means one can (pretty much) think '$=$'

Comment: Oh okay. I have one last question: how can we consider $\bigoplus _{i\in I}G$ to be an analogue of the free abelian group on the set of simplices? Do you have any references for this?

Comment: the coproduct gives it the the universal property of a free abelian group. If you don't like that, then it would help to give your definition of free abelian group on $I$.

Comment: @AndresMejia I define the free abelian group on a set $I$ to be the set of finite formal $\mathbb Z$-linear combinations of elements of $I$, isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{i\in I} \mathbb Z$.